# Pairs of integers $(a,b)$ such that $\frac{1}{6} =\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How many pairs of integers are there $(a,b)$ with $a \leq b$ such that $$\frac{1}{6} =\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}$$

My attempt:
Clearing fractions we get $$ab = 6(a+b)$$
$$ \Longrightarrow \frac{ab}{a+b} = 6$$

Which means that $ab$ is a multiple of $a+b$ since the answer is an integer. Also $ab \equiv 0\pmod{a+b}$.

Any ideas or a hint to help me continue? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

HINT : $$ab=6(a+b)\iff (a-6)(b-6)=36.$$

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for that. My question is how did you know to add $36$ to each side? Who would've thought of doing that?

Comment: @AspiringMathlete: This is a common technique. It's worth remembering : $ab=c(a+b)\iff ab-ca-cb=0\iff ab-ca-cb+c^2=c^2\iff (a-c)(b-c)=c^2.$